# Connecting to Amazon Web Services S3

Tags: python, image, amazon-s3

I have several images stored in folder inside a bucket in Amazon S3. I was wondering how can I write a simple script to access those images in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) for this. To download a file [download_file](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) is the API.